# How do I show that $A=\{f \in E, |f(x)>0, \; \forall \; x \in [0,1]\}$ is not open in $(E,\| *\|_1)$ for $E=C([0,1],\mathbb{R})$?

Tags: general-topology

How do I show that $A=\{f \in E, |f(x)>0, \; \forall \; x \in [0,1]\}$ is not open in $(E,\| *\|_1)$ for $E=C([0,1],\mathbb{R})$ ?

I'm sorry I couldn't find any similar enough question.

I'm a beginner in topology and I'm getting used to show that something is closed or open but not to showing that something is not open.

I understand that I could use the set $E-A$ and show that it is not closed, but I don't have any ideas in mind and I don't think that would be the good way to show it.

Thank you!

Ps: the norm is defined as the integral from zero to one of the absolute value of the function.

Comment: what is $f$ and what do you mean by $f(x)$ when $x\in C([0,1];\mathbb{R})$, composition?

Comment: I want to make sure of something: when you write $x \in E$ you're referring to a continuous function $[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ and not a point in $[0,1]$?  Then your condition defining $A$ is about function composition and not simply that $f(x)>0$ at a point $x$?  Also, which function $f$ is the set $A$ defined by?

Comment: E is composed of continuous functions, I'm sorry I messed up over there, I will fix it

Comment: Your question is still phrased ambiguously.  It should really be stated as: "Given $x \in [0,1]$ let $A = \{f \in E \; | \; f(x)>0\}$...."

Comment: Well I didn't really think that would matter for the result, does it? because $\| \|_1$ is an integral from 0 to 1. Sorry about that, I will fix it.

Comment: It matters that your writing is clear.  When you write $f$, it implies that $f \in E$, but if you write $f(x)$ then you have evaluated the function at a point and it implies that $f(x) \in \mathbb{R}$.  With your current edits, is it that you want your functions $f$ to be positive *for all* $x \in [0,1]$, or is there simply a single point $x \in [0,1]$ you want $f$ to be positive at?

Comment: I changed it, my bad, wrote it and did not think about it. To be clear, f is a function positive in every point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let 
$$A = \{f\in E \ | \ f(x) > 0, \forall x\in [0,1]\}$$
Given any $f\in A$, it suffices to show that for any ball
$$B(f,\epsilon) = \bigg\{ g\in E \ | \ \int|f-g|dx < \epsilon \bigg\}$$
there exists some function $h \in E$ such that $h\in B(f,\epsilon) $, but $h \not\in A$. In other words, $A$ has no open ball containing $f$. To do this, let

$$h_\delta(x) =  \ \begin{cases}\frac{f(\delta)x}{\delta} + \frac{(x-\delta)}{\delta}, \ x\in [0,\delta] \\
f(x) , x\in [\delta,1] \end{cases}$$
So $h_\delta$ on $[0,\delta]$ is the line from $(0,-1)$ to $(\delta, f(\delta))$. Then 
$$||h_\delta - f||_1 \leq \delta(\max_{x\in [0,\delta]}f(x) + 1)$$
therefore set
$$\delta  = \min\{\frac{\epsilon}{2}\frac{1}{(\max_{x\in [0,1]}f(x) + 1)},1\}$$
Hence $h_\delta \in B(f,\epsilon)$, but $h_\delta\not\in A$.

Comment: I would also like to note that this proof fails for $L^\infty$, and actually you will find $A$ is open!

Comment: That's really elegant, but A has no open ball containing $f$ sounds absurd, you mean h, right?

Comment: I mean, there is no open ball $B$ containing $f$ such that $B \subset A$.  Any such ball must have points outside of $A$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: A clear way to do this is to show that given any $\epsilon>0$ and any $f \in E$ that there exists a function $g \not\in A$ that is $\epsilon$-close to $f$ in $(E,||\cdot||_1)$. Here is a general construction I will offer, but you should fill in the details for yourself.

Given $f \in A$ is continuous and $[0,1]$ is compact, there exists a point $x_{min}$ which is the minimum of $f$.  Given $\epsilon>0$, and some value $\delta < \min\{x_{min}, 1 - x_{min}\}$ construct a function $g \in E$ of the form:

$$
g(x) \;\; =\;\; \begin{cases}
f(x), & \text{if} \; x \in [0,x_{min}-\delta] \\
m_1x + b_1, & \text{if} \; x \in [x_{min}-\delta, x_{min}] \\
m_2x + b_2, & \text{if} \; x \in [x_{min}, x_{min}+\delta] \\
f(x), & \text{if} \; x \in [x_{min}+\delta, 1] \\
\end{cases}.
$$

What you'll see here is that in finding $||f - g||_1$ this will reduce to an integral in the interval $[x_{min} - \delta, x_{min} + \delta]$.  Pick the values for the straight lines so that $g(x_{min})\leq0$ and the total area bounded between the difference of these two functions is $<\epsilon$.